# Fail to launch ghcid in terminal in VSCode -----showing terminated with exit code: 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, ghcid

I'm very new to vscode as well as ghcid. When I follow the instruction to open the Command Palette and type " Start Ghcid", then it shows
" The terminal process "ghcid '--outputfile=/var/folders/4k/0c49wtss7dgb9n872y99hzh40000gn/T/ghcid-15bcb70c9b4c8926f1ca.txt'" terminated with exit code: 1." on the bottom right.

I have googled it, but the issue is only related with the special characters in the name which is not relate with my problem. I can open my terminal successfully, only failed when I try to launch the ghcid.

Since I just start to learn Haskell by myself, if you could answer my question step by step, I would really appreciate it!!!! Thanks.

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Read this article: https://dev.to/egregors/vscode-for-haskell-in-2020-5dn8 (it has some extra tips that should make your Haskell/VSCode experience more productive), 2) See if "/var/folders/4k/0c49wtss7dgb9n872y99hzh40000gn/T/ghcid-15bcb70c9b4c8926f1ca.txt" exists, and post back what it says.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replying! But here is a really silly question, how can I test whether a file is existing?  Should I just type the name in my terminal?

Comment: Here is what I have done, I typed directly in my terminal: /var/folders/4k/0c49wtss7dgb9n872y99hzh40000gn/T/ghcid-15bcb70c9b4c8926f1ca.txt       It shows back:
bash: /var/folders/4k/0c49wtss7dgb9n872y99hzh40000gn/T/ghcid-15bcb70c9b4c8926f1ca.txt: Permission denied

Comment: It sounds like you're on Linux ... and it sounds like you need to learn a bit about how to to navigate your way around Linux before you can hope to accomplish anything.  Q: How do I test if a file exists?  A: `ls -l  /var/folders/4k/0c49wtss7dgb9n872y99hzh40000gn/T/ghcid-15bcb70c9b4c8926f1ca.txt`  Q: How do I see what's in the file?  A: `cat  /var/folders/4k/0c49wtss7dgb9n872y99hzh40000gn/T/ghcid-15bcb70c9b4c8926f1ca.txt`.  There are also GUI tools to accomplish exactly the same thing.  But I have no idea *which* (if any) GUI desktop is on your system :(

Comment: Ok, that's clear enough. So, I type as you written. When I use ls -l to check the specific content it gives: -rw-r--r--  1 sarah  staff  0 12 30 11:03 /var/folders/4k/0c49wtss7dgb9n872y99hzh40000gn/T/ghcid-15bcb70c9b4c8926f1ca.txt  And when I try to use "cat" to see the content, it doesn't respond. What can I do next？By the way, I use Mac OS system, sorry I should point it out earlier. : )

Comment: Also to figure out what content in that txt file, I use "open" and type the path, it gives me a txt file without any text. Should I just delete that file? @paulsm4